# Java unique code generation failed while calling the recurring function

Tags: java, hibernate, logic, unique-key

We have to implement a logic to write the unique code generation in Java. The concept is when we generate the code the system will check if the code is already generate or not. If already generate the system create new code and check again. But this logic fails in some case and we cannot able to identify what is the issue is

Here is the code to create the unique code

Integer code = null;

```
try {
    int max = 999999;
    int min = 100000;
    code = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    PreOrders preObj = null;
    preObj = WebServiceDao.getInstance().preOrderObj(code.toString());
    if (preObj != null) {
        createCode();
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    exceptionCaught();
    e.printStackTrace();
    log.error("Exception in method createCode() - " + e.toString());
}
return code;
```

}

The function `preOrderObj` is calling a function to check the code exists in the database if exists return the object. We are using Hibernate to map the database functions and Mysql on the backend.

Here is the function `preOrderObj`

```
PreOrders preOrderObj = null;
        List<PreOrders> preOrderList = null;
        SessionFactory sessionFactory =
                (SessionFactory) ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getAttribute(HibernateListener.KEY_NAME);
        Session Hibernatesession = sessionFactory.openSession();
        try {
            Hibernatesession.beginTransaction();
            preOrderList = Hibernatesession.createCriteria(PreOrders.class).add(Restrictions.eq("code", code)).list(); // removed .add(Restrictions.eq("status", true))
            if (!preOrderList.isEmpty()) {
                preOrderObj = (PreOrders) preOrderList.iterator().next();
            }
            Hibernatesession.getTransaction().commit();
            Hibernatesession.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Hibernatesession.getTransaction().rollback();
            log.debug("This is my debug message.");
            log.info("This is my info message.");
            log.warn("This is my warn message.");
            log.error("This is my error message.");
            log.fatal("Fatal error " + e.getStackTrace().toString());
        } finally {
            Hibernatesession.close();
        }
        return preOrderObj;
    }
```

Please guide us to identify the issue.

Comment: So what happens for "this logic fails in some case and we cannot able to identify what is the issue is", any exception?

Comment: For example the code 122334 code is already in the database, in some case the system send this code back even if this code is already exists. We cannot identify in which case this code is allow to return same code that is already exists in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `createCode` method, when the random code generated already exist in database, you try to call `createCode` again. However, the return value from the recursive call is not updated to the `code` variable, hence the colliding `code` is still returned and cause error.

To fix the problem, update the method as

```
...
    if (preObj != null) {
        //createCode();
        code = createCode();
    }  
...
```

Such that the code is updated.
By the way, using random number to generate unique value and test uniqueness through query is a bit strange. You may try [Auto Increment](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) if you want unique value.

Comment: But we are initializing the code again on createCode() function itself here code = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);

Comment: But the `code` is not returned to the caller. Please note that `code` is local variable and each call has different `code`.